# Laravel Nova action models empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Here is my action.

```
public function actions(Request $request)
{
    return [
        new ApprovedUserAction,
        (new RejectUserAction)->make()->standalone(),
    ];
}
```

This is my action code.

```
{
    Log::info('test',['test' => $models]);
    Log::info('test',['field' => $fields]);
    foreach ($models as $model) {
        Log::info("here);
        $actionEvent = ActionEvent::forResourceUpdate(auth()->user(), $model);

        $model->update(['status' => 'reject']);
        $actionEvent->save();
    }

    return $models;
    // return Action::message('You have been Updated');
}
```

Why the models' values are empty??

I want to update the selected values, but the models return an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

When its a standalone action these fields are omitted since it works on a whole resource and not selected records.

There are a few solutions here but i think creating two actions, one for the whole resource if you need a standalone and one for a collection of models if you need to select them.

Unless nova 4 released the other day has a better solution.

Here is link to relevant documentation for nova 3.
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/actions/registering-actions.html#standalone-actions